# Only one connection to not lose message

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, sendmessage, channel

I have an application with a base controller, base html and base javascript file. In this three a create a token with unique client id (create_channel) and I pass the token to the template and create the connection in the javascript file.

Then I send a message to this connection. If I stay in the same page it works well  and I see the message but if I go to other page the base.js is load again and new connection is started so I never see the message that I sent from the server.

Any idea how can I resolve this issue? I only want to create one connection but the base file is load more times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each "user" has to have an ID. I use the session ID. Then you create the token against that only if it does not already exist.

```
channel_token = self.session.get('channel_token')
    if channel_token is None: # if the session user does not have a channel token
        user_id = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-",'')
        channel_token = channel.create_channel(user_id)
        self.session['channel_token'] = channel_token
        self.session['user_id'] = user_id
```

So when you go to a different page you don't create a new channel if one already is available for that user_Id. When the user navigates away you'll get a disconnect/connect each time. And you can use the `user_id` to send the message regardless of what page they are on.

Comment: This is solve my problem for the token but when base javascript file is load other connection is created, with the same token but other conexion so the message is lost becuase I put in $(function() {
 
 var token = $('#token').val();
 
 channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
    socket = channel.open(); Any idea? Where can I put it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but here is a demo I wrote, perhaps it's of use: https://github.com/Paul1234321/channelapidemo you can see it running here (for the time being) http://pppredictor.appspot.com/

Comment: Good example! My 'problem' is that I have your javascript that you use in the <script> in html template I put in a base.js (it is load with all templates) so if I change the template I want to see the notification too. But at this moment I am creating other connection. Are any way to know if a connection is open?

Comment: Ah, I see. I've not faced that problem yet. There is a way to tell if a connection exists, when it's created the client will do a POST to _ah/channel/connected/ as detailed here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview#Tracking_Client_Connections_and_Disconnections so I guess you can track who is connected and not allow the .js to create another connection for that particular user if one already exists.